# Future-proofing data types(i.e creating structs with only one member in hopes they can be expanded later, when needed)

Tags: list, oop, object

Say I want to create a list of variables/objects to store something very specific(say the coordinate for where an enemy needs to spawn in a videogame), at first I would only need a simple point in space to store this information but later on I may want to add the enemy type and other data specific to each element of this list. Is it good practice to write a whole new class or struct with only just the initial data member I need in hopes that whenever I need to update the list with more data per element I can just add members to this previously redundant struct/class? Furthermore, is packaging an already existing type into a new one in the spirit of being more descriptive something that actually helps code readability?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classic case for some good old object orientated programming.

So the idea would basically be that you have your simple struct/class with, as mentioned in your example, coordinates. If you would want to add another enemy with some extra attributes to be stored you would go ahead and create a new class/struct that *inherits* from the very basic class. That way you get all the attributes the basic class had in your new class plus you can define new ones.

That way you have a good structure in your code and it is easy to understand what is going on. Scalability and reusability also profit greatly from this, which is why this concept is state-of-the-art.

This might sound a little confusing at first, but I recommend to read up on inheritance and object oriented programming in general. I promise it is not too hard once you get used to the thinking patterns.

Comment: ye,I am aware of this of course.What I mean rather is that sometimes it is unexpected to find oneself having to change a list of simple types into something a bit larger.Say at first you only need simple point coordinates for where the enemies spawn,but much later you figure that since enemies will have some other feature they ALL share it would be convenient to group up the coordinates with data for this feature.My question regards where we should draw the line between the blissful simplicity of storing just the coordinates and the hideous complexity of making every simple type into a struct.

Comment: well if they all share that feature you add it in the base class... sorry, but i don't think you understood. the problem you are describing can be solved by beautiful oop with ease.

Comment: I think calling it beautiful is opinionated, and no, im not asking for OOP basics here, im asking a question about programming style. Is it smarter to put every int,bool,float and string etc into their own struct whenever you put them in a list? For future`s sake? Or is it a bad practice?